# YouTube v3 API error: ipRefererBlocked

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am attempting to add a YouTube video feed to a website.

- I have created the Project and turned on the YouTube data API in the developers console.
- I have created a browser key and added the domain to the list of referrers as `*.domain.com/` as per their example. I've also tried `http://domain.com` & `domain.com` as variations

If I remove the referrer, it works. Otherwise, I get this error message:

```
There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Based on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27483674/1197605) with a similar error message, it sounds like there is a (possibly-undocumented) order of operations that needs to be adhered to or that error is received.  If you follow the steps in _both_ answers, does it resolve the issue?

Comment: thanks for that, but I'd already seen that question. have deleted and started from scratch in the correct order and still no joy. :(

Comment: Two things I can think of from this Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591012/youtube-api-permission-403-forbidden-error. 1. Is your key generated properly? 2. Are the requests coming from same IP address?

Comment: I checked the key and regenerated it and still no luck. also yes, all coming from the same IP.